# Cannot read property 'config' of null TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: angular

when i run this command ng serve,i have this error can someone tell me why

> Cannot read property 'config' of null TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'config' of null
>       at Class.run (C:\wamp64\www\back_front\front_end\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:51:63)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (C:\wamp64\www\back_front\front_end\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Comment: do you have  .angular-cli.json file ? try to copy it from a project thats already working and let us know.

Comment: I have an angular.json file, not angular-cli.json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs when angular cannot find `.angular-cli.json` file (Do note there is a dot in the file name). Usually it is a hidden file.

### Try these steps first:

- Delete your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file
- npm install
- npm uninstall -g angular-cli
- npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
- npm install -g @angular/cli
- ng serve

If it still produces the same error, then you will actually need `.angular-cli.json` file.

**Default `.angular-cli.json` file:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "PROJECT_NAME"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

**Note:** This is just a default file, you will need to configure your project settings in this file.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy `angular-cli.json` from a working project.

I personally use  `rsync -rtv  angularWorking-project-folder  /destination-folder`.  This helps to copy also hidden files.